# Linux How can I find out if the server has USB2 or USB3

Tags: usb

I have a server that I do not have documentation and I plan to buy a USB Storage Device that is USB3 and now I want to find out if the server has USB2 or USB3.

I tried

```
dmesg | grep usb

[    1.337094] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.337101] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.337120] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.545696] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.545699] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.545702] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.545704] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 ehci_hcd
[    1.545707] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.565669] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.565671] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.565674] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.565676] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 ehci_hcd
[    1.565678] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.873567] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.893527] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    2.021963] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8008
[    2.021976] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.041898] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    2.041899] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.309587] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.447522] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bb4, idProduct=2910
[    2.447524] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.447525] usb 1-1.3: Product: portable SSD
[    2.447526] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Intenso
[    2.447527] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 07076349A77F4990
[    2.449093] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.449841] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
[    2.450040] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.450551] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    2.525517] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.635029] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=2212
[    2.635034] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.635038] usb 1-1.5: Product: Officejet Pro L7600
[    2.635041] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: HP
[    2.635044] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: MY768550M5
[    2.635883] usb-storage 1-1.5:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.635995] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1.5:1.3
[   23.960989] usblp 1-1.5:1.1: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 4 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x2212
[   23.961022] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
```

I do not understand much, but it looks to me as if there is only USB1 und USB2

if there another way to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logs it looks like the system has EHCI USB controller. This means USB2. Try **`grep`** for XHCI.

I would use the information provided by **`dmidecode -t 2`** to find the model of the motherboard. Then you would probably be able to find the specs online.

Comment: grep for xhci is None so USB2 , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Krasi I discovered the dmidecode, and the option :

**dmidecode --type connector**

so I have 4 USB 3.0 Ports

```
Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: PS2
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Keyboard
        External Connector Type: PS/2
        Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: PS2
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
        External Connector Type: PS/2
        Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: VGA
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: VGA
        External Connector Type: DB-15 female
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: DisplayPort
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: DisplayPort
        External Connector Type: Other
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: DisplayPort
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: DisplayPort 2
        External Connector Type: Other
        Port Type: Video Port

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: RJ45/USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: LAN
        External Connector Type: RJ-45
        Port Type: Network Port

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: IN/OUT
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear line in
        External Connector Type: Mini DIN
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: IN/OUT
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear line out
        External Connector Type: Mini DIN
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: FRONT AUD
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Front mic in
        External Connector Type: Mini DIN
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: FRONT AUD
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Front headphone/line out
        External Connector Type: Mini DIN
        Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: SPKR
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x002A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Not Specified
        Internal Connector Type: Proprietary
        External Reference Designator: Front USB Port 1
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x002B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Not Specified
        Internal Connector Type: Proprietary
        External Reference Designator: Front USB Port 2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x002C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Not Specified
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Front USB 3.0 Port 1
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: Not Specified
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Front USB 3.0 Port 2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x002E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: REAR USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB Port 1
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x002F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: REAR USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB Port 2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0030, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: RJ45/USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB Port 3
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: RJ45/USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB Port 4
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0032, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB 3.0 Port 1
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: USB
        Internal Connector Type: None
        External Reference Designator: Rear USB 3.0 Port 2
        External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: MEDIA 3.0
        Internal Connector Type: Proprietary
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: USB

Handle 0x0035, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: SATA1
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0036, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: MSATA
        Internal Connector Type: SAS/SATA Plug Receptacle
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: SATA

Handle 0x0037, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: SATAPWR
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: CHFAN
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: CHFAN2
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: PB/LED (Power Button and Front LED)
        Internal Connector Type: Proprietary
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: None
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: HLCK
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: Other
        Port Type: Other

Handle 0x003F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
        Internal Reference Designator: HSNR
        Internal Connector Type: Other
        External Reference Designator: Not Specified
        External Connector Type: Other
        Port Type: Other
```